# Conditional Independence Equivalent Definitions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I do not understand how

P(A|B,C)=P(A|C)

is derived from

P(A∩B|C)=P(A|C)P(B|C)

on this [site](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_4_conditional_independence.php).

I'm stuck on the statement:

> By conditioning on C, we obtain
> P(A|B,C)=P(A∩B|C)/P(B|C)

Should the left hand side of the equation be P(A|B|C)?

**Update**

From this [site](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_4_conditional_independence.php):

Definition

> Two events A and B are conditionally independent given an event C with
> P(C)>0 if
>
> P(A ∩ B | C)=P(A | C) P(B | C)    equation (1.8)
>
> Recall that from the definition of conditional probability,
>
> P(A | B) = P(A ∩ B) P(B),
>
> if P(B)>0. By conditioning on C, we obtain
>
> P(A | B , C) = P(A ∩ B | C) P(B | C)

How is this last equation `P(A | B , C)= P(A ∩ B | C) P(B | C)` derived? What does it mean to condition on C?

Comment: "*Should the left hand side be... (expression with multiple |'s)?*"  No.  Such a statement does not make grammatical sense.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'm not sure what "conditioning on" a event such as C means.

Comment: So, $\Pr(A\mid B\cap C) = \dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)}{\Pr(B\cap C)}$ by definition... which if we divide both numerator and denominator by $\Pr(C)$ we get $\dfrac{\frac{\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)}{\Pr(C)}}{\frac{\Pr(B\cap C)}{\Pr(C)}}$,  the fraction in the numerator being precisely $\Pr(A\cap B\mid C)$ and so on, giving the result

Comment: $P(A|B\color{red}{\cap} C)$ is better (at first) than $P(A|B\color{red}, C)$, isn't it ?

Comment: So, with Pr(∣∩), we're trying to find the probability that event A occurs given that B and C has occurred. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  As for considering $\cap$ vs a comma... both are used.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I'm going to take some time to study / think about why finding that probability makes sense with respect to the probability of A and B occurring giving that C has occurred. I have to say that I thought "conditioning on C" meant some event(s) (e.g., A, A∩B, etc.) occurs given C occurred. I guess I was wrong there.

Comment: @James: I don’t understand your comment. In the previous comments, your understanding that $\mathsf P(A\mid B\cap C)$ is the probability that $A$ occurs given $B$ and $C$ occur was correct. Why are you now concluding that this isn’t the meaning of “conditioning on $C$”?

Comment: I suppose I don't understand the term, "conditioning on." My (likely incorrect) understanding is that conditional probability is the probability of some event(s) (e.g., X) given that another event (e.g., Y) occurred such that P(X ∩ Y) / P(X) = P(Y |X). I figured "conditioning on C" means letting X = C, but I see P(  ∣  ∩ ) instead of P( ∩  | ) in @JMoravitz explanation and the site I referenced.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me why that site and @JMorvaitz is stating that A is conditionally dependent on  ∩ . A is supposed to be only conditional on C.

Comment: Where did I say that $A$ is conditionally dependent on $B\cap C$?  I mean... it might be, or it might not... but are you asking why we brought up talking about $\Pr(A\mid B\cap C)$ in the first place?  It is because we were tasked with proving that $\Pr(A\mid B\cap C)$ is equal to $\Pr(A\mid C)$ given certain conditions... so we start with the expression on the left, and through a sequence of rephrasing and algebraic manipulation, invoking the various necessary definitions,... we eventually show that they are indeed equal.

Comment: We showed $\Pr(A\mid B\cap C) = \cdots = \cdots = \Pr(A\mid C)$ where somewhere in the middle in those $\cdots$ we used the hypothesis that $\Pr(A\cap B\mid C)=\Pr(A\mid C)\Pr(B\mid C)$... and since equality is transitive.... we are done.  Why are we trying to show this?  Because this is quite literally *what you were asking about how to show*.

Comment: @JMoravitz - I'm sorry that I can't seem to understand this. The site I was referencing started with P(A ∩ B | C) = P(A | C) P(B | C) equation (labeled 1.8). Then, it states "By conditioning on C, we obtain P(A | B ∩ C) = P(A ∩ B | C) / P(B | C)." I thought A, B, and C events were the same events described in equation 1.8. I guess I'm wrong because A in equation 1.8 is only conditional on C not B and C.

Comment: If we suppose that it is true that $\Pr(A\cap B\mid C)=\Pr(A\mid C)\Pr(B\mid C)$... i.e. that "$A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent of one another given $C$"... then it follows that $\Pr(A\mid B\cap C)$ happens to be equal to $\Pr(A\mid C)$.  Period.  Full stop.  Yes, these are the same $A,B,C$.  The first half of the sentence is the hypothesis.  The second half of the sentence is the conclusion.  Yes... in the hypothesis we talk about conditioning only on $C$ and nothing else.  Yes... in the conclusion we talk about conditioning on both $B$ and $C$.  What is confusing about this?

Comment: You seem to be hung up on the "By conditioning on C" part of the words they used.  Ignore it.  That was just one of many ways that one could follow along with the steps they took to get to the end result of proving what they wanted to.  I explained that step by "Just divide both numerator and denominator by $C$"...\

Comment: As to the question "*How is this last step derived*" I explained that days ago... in already full detail... in my second comment.  We begin with $\Pr(A\mid B\cap C)$ and we expand that using the definition of conditional probability, we divide both numerator and denominator by $\Pr(C)$ which you will note that since we divided both numerator and denominator by the same amount doesn't change the overall value... and then we reinterpreted each of the numerator and denominator as conditional probabilities themselves.  We then use the hypothesis, and then cancel, giving the final result.

Comment: @JMoravitz "If we suppose that it is true that Pr(∩∣)=Pr(∣)Pr(∣)... i.e. that " and  are conditionally independent of one another given "... then it follows that Pr(∣∩) happens to be equal to Pr(∣)." Yes I see that now. Thanks for your help. I just don't understand where they get P(A | B,C)=P(A∩B|C)/ P(B|C).

Comment: By the way couldn't we also say P(B | A, C) = P(B | C)?

Comment: Of course. The roles of $A$ and $B$ are symmetrical in the above problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz - Many thanks for your help and patience with me. With your latest help, I reviewed all your comments again. I now fully understand your second comment (and upvoted). That's really the answer to my question, but your other comments immensely helped me to get there. Thank you again. You are a great teacher / explainer of this. If you want post that as an answer, I will definitely accept and upvote.